# UITableView - Change text field that's on the same row as the button being pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been experimenting with table views for the first time, and am confused as to how UI elements such as text fields are differentiated between when taking action on cells (e.g. pressing a button).

Right now I have a button and a text field on each row. To make this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"gameCell";
    gameViewCell *cell = [tableView
                        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    long row = [indexPath row];

//Button to change text field
    strokeUp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    strokeUp.frame = CGRectMake(248.0f, 11.0f, 80.0f, 32.0f);
    [strokeUp setTag:indexPath.row];
    [strokeUp addTarget:self action:@selector(addStroke:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:strokeUp];

//Text field that changes (puts '1' in box for now)
    strokesBox = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(223.0f, 11.0f, 37.0f, 32.0f)];
    strokesBox.delegate = self;
    [strokesBox setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:strokesBox];

    return cell;
}
```

And this is what I'm doing when the strokeUp button is tapped. I want the text field that's on the same row as the button to display '1' (later it'll add 1 to what's currently in the box). The number of rows varies from 2 to 6 depending on how many rows the user chose in the previous screen.

```
- (void)addStroke:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:table];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (senderButton.tag == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Row 1");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextField *sampleField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
        theTextField = @"1";
    }
    else if (senderButton.tag == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Row 2");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextField *sampleField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        sampleField.text = @"1";
    }
}
```

Comment: Its better to use custom cell instead of adding the controls in the table view cell as Jay Gajjar's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the tag of textfield different from button say

```
    [strokesBox setTag:indexPath.row+10];


// and set this code in action


- (void)addStroke:(id)sender
{
    int tag = [(UIButton *)sender tag] 
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[table viewWithTag:tag+10];
    textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tag+1];
}
```

Comment: what if i have 12 buttons in table?

Answer (score 1):

More convinent way would be to create a custom cell and make `IBOutlets` of buttons & textfields.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"gameCell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addStroke:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

And then in addStoke: method use

```
CustomCell *cell =(CustomCell) [sender superView];
```

Now you can manipulate the textfield text of cell

```
cell.textField1.text=@"test1";
```

Here is the tutorial for custom cell
**http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/**

Comment: @Ganapathy, it may be simple, but it's not fine. The button's superview will not be the cell, but the cell's contentView. And depending on whether you're in iOS 6 or iOS 7, the contentView's superview may or may not be the cell either.

Comment: Yes i accepted. i mentioned only for the custom cell re-use as i mentioned in the question comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below

first use array to set value in textfield as below code

```
strokesBox = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(223.0f, 11.0f, 37.0f, 32.0f)];
strokesBox.delegate = self;
[strokesBox setTag:indexPath.row];
[strokesBox setText:[myMutableArray objectatindex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:strokesBox];
```

now on button click change the value in array and update the cell as bellow

```
- (void)addStroke:(id)sender
{
  [myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:@"1"];

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[indexPaths release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
- (void)addStroke:(id)sender{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
    for (UITextField *textField in [cell subviews]) {
        if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            textField.text=@"Rajneesh";
        }
    }
}
```